# What are those red glowing monsters supposed to be?

Tags: borderlands-2

I was driving to do some mission when suddenly a red glowing monster just spawned in front of me.

[image: Screenshot of red glowing Bullymong]

Are they some kind of rare? Because he was pretty easy and not a Badass.

Comment: I think that's just a Bullymong with a graphical glitch

Comment: I encountered this same Bullymong and as far as I could tell there was nothing special about it other than the red glow.

Comment: Do you play it on pc or ps4? I haven't seen this on pc which makes me think that this is a glitch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've seen some objects, like bullymong snow pile and pile of trash to glow with a similarly bright, but green glow.

This is a glitch.

P.S.: but a glitched monster definitely seems much more intriguing than a glitched pile! :)

Comment: Breakable objects are supposed to have a noticeable (but not extreme) green glow/green gas effect to indicate that they're breakable, like how containers have a green light to show they can be opened.

Comment: True, but this was definitely not **that** glow - my reflexes are honed by Borderlands 1 :) The glow I saw was analogous to one pictured - rich green tint covering entire model, with color "bleeding" outside some distance in screen space.

Comment: I saw this appear on a spider ant as I drove away from Ellie's place.  Though funnily it wasn't the ant that was glowing, it was the hole he jumped out of.

Comment: Oh, I failed to mention the glow was on a **destroyed** pile - like with Jeff's ant hole (and OP's bullymong corpse), these were just temporary debris objects.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that same red bullymong in the exact same spot everytime I reach that point in the game. if it is a glitch then it is a weird one because the glow doesn't go away after it dies or anything and it actually emits light instead of just being a different texture.

Answer (score -1):

I just killed that same red glowing bullymong in that same spot. I spent a few minutes wondering if there was something special about it, but not as far as I can see.