# Borderlands 2 Discolored Objects

Tags: borderlands-2

Time and time again I've found seemingly random objects with incorrect coloring. One occurrence also had the object out of place as well (7 and 8). Which then got discolored as well the next time I was looking at it (9). Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

[image: 1]
1

[image: 2]
2

[image: 3]
3

[image: 4]
4

[image: 5]
5

[image: 6]
6

[image: 7]
7

[image: 8]
8

[image: 9]
9

[image: 10]
10

[image: 11]
11

[image: 12]
12

Comment: You might want to check the temperature of your graphics card. I've seen animations freeze and textures scramble when graphics cards start to overheat.

Comment: That looks like corrupted textures.  Usually graphics cards artifact, but sometimes something like this happens.

Comment: Try reinstalling borderlands through steam, back up your saves first

Comment: @Brian It might also have to do with what exactly I'm using as a graphics card. With the Intel Core i5 4200U I'm pretty sure the graphics card is built into the processor, so the GPU temperature should be the temperature of the CPU. If I look at the graphics area of [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) it says Intel HD Graphics family which would appear to be the part of the processor that controls graphics. The CPU section of the software indicates a temperature only slightly higher than when the game is closed. No signs of an overheat. When the game is running the CPU usage is very low.

Comment: The only thing that I think could cause this is I purchased this game through a browser not on the laptop on which the game is installed. Once purchased I saw a button that said download. Curious, because I was on iOS and the game shouldn't be able to be installed on iOS, I decided to push the button. As it turned out, the button allowed for remote installation of the game. This commenced immediately resulting in no option for a start menu shortcut or a desktop shortcut. This seemed to be a new feature so it may have had some bugs during download which may explain corrupted textures/sprites.

Comment: @lramos15 Would the only thing I need to do to back up my saves be save all the .sav files and the profile.bin under "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\76561198044858764"?

Comment: That should do it, it might be good to backup the whole documents borderlands folder just in case. Steam might keep your saves but it's good to be safe

Comment: @lramos15 Okay. Will do. I'll also look it up in case there's a little more too it. Better safe then sorry!

Comment: This definitely has no relation to how you have bought the game. This seems to be a random glitch in the game's drawing code - it happened to me several times on a grown-up nVidia 250 GTS. Also, another glitch happens: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86682/

Comment: It looks like the colours are directly inverting their RGB values..

Answer (score 2):

**The surface may have been assigned both a primary colour and a texture, but the texture can not be found.**

In game developing, there are various errors, bugs or glitches that can cause a texture to be displayed incorrectly.

They can be blamed on anything from corruption of the game data to malfunction on the graphic cards side. This reminds me mostly of an issue I would encounter (predominantly in OpenGL) where the texture would either be missing, or otherwise not readable in the current context.

Textures are often used with a 'wash' colour to give the intended appearance, but if the texture is corrupt or otherwise unusable, all you get is the bright clear wash colour.

I hope this helps, but this does not come from any experience I have had playing the game, as it does from my experience as a video game developer.

Comment: I was about to say this doesn't answer the question of how to fix it - but the OP only asked why it was happening and this *does* answer that :)